# program that scans a header file, and reports utilizable code?

Tags: c++, c, header, static-analysis

When I include a header file, I often wonder what was pulled in.

- What functions are now available to me?
- what classes can I instantiate and what are their functions?
- Is anything wrapped in a namespace?
- Is anything in the global namespace?

Documentation does not always answer these questions nor provide any guarantee.

I could look at the source, but it becomes difficult to observe for large header files that also include a tree of other headers.
Is there any good programs out there to do this kind of analysis?

Comment: Instead of what functions/classes/etc. may be available by including a specific header file, you should look at what functions/classes/etc. you _need_ and then look for the header file it's defined/declared in. Use a reference site [such as this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/) to search for whatever you need, it will tell you what header files you need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a tool like [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/). You feed it your library's sources and it outputs cross-referenced documentation.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `-E` (or `/E`; all C and C++ compilers used to have this option using exactly this name) option of the compiler to get a preprocessed output of a translation unit. This dumps all declarations seen by the compiler. It seems, you are after just the functions and classes while the `-E` option would also write all declarations. If you really just want the functions and classes, you could use the clang library to get hold of the abstract syntax tree (AST) and dump out just these.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Visual Studio, an option for this is using code helpers such as MS intellisense, [wholetomato visual assist](http://www.wholetomato.com/) or [resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/). These may provide you with all accessible variables, classes, functions, types, namespaces, constants, etc... in a given context.

Other IDEs may provide this feature too but I've never used it other than in Visual Studio. It seems like QtCreator may be a good option as pointed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/780837/what-is-a-good-linux-ide-for-code-completion).